# How do I separate my angular front end from my node/express back-end with nginx on Digital Ocean?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

Currently and successfully I have a node.js app that lives on a Digital Ocean server. I have a single Github repo for the entire app. In my routes in express when a certain route is hit ('/') I render an EJS template which has my HTML/CSS/Angular. This works - but is not what I want.

What I want is to have my HTML/CSS/Angular completely separate from my node back-end.

I want that front-end to have its own Github repo.  The problem I am running into is I am finding it hard to find resources that tell me how to set up my app this way - the tutorials I have found teach me how to do it the way I already have it done.

What I want:

1. A user enters a url and the appropriate html page is rendered (without using node/express)
2. My angular will then hit my back-end endpoints for whatever it needs

How do I:

1. Set up my single IP address server on Digital Ocean to do this?
2. Do I need to do anything specific for static file delivery?

Comment: I don't know how to do this through digital ocean, but basically nginx would be your front, listening on port 80, and it would serve your static directory containing your angular files, and it would have a reverse proxy that proxies to your node app running on some other port.